# Как поместить обЪект на задний план

Tags: html, css

[![введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body, h1, h2,h3,h4, p,a {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
  }

@font-face {
  src: url(../fonts/NeueMachina-Regular.woff);
  font-family: "neuenormal";
  font-weight:normal;
}
  
@font-face {
  src: url(../fonts/NeueMachina-Ultrabold.woff);
  font-family: "neuebold";
  font-weight: bold;
}

  

@font-face {
  src: url(../fonts/SpecifyPERSONAL-ExExpBlack.woff);
  font-family: "specify";
  font-weight: bold;
}



  .holst {
      /*background: url(../img/back.jpg) center no-repeat;*/
      background-size: cover;
      background-color: darkslategrey;
      
  }

  .border {
    border: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: white;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    width: 1400px;
    margin:0 auto;
  }

  .header {
    font-family: AvenirNext;
    list-style: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  .ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    border: solid;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: white;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-top: none;
  }
  
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
  }

  .textheader {
    color:white;
    font-size: 30px;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: neuebold;
  }

  a {
    border: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  .navbar {
  }
  
  .promotions {
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-left: 50px;

  }

  .smm {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: specify;
    font-size:55px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #00B1D2;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    line-height: 0.9;
  }

  .promotion {
    color: #00B1D2;
    font-size:100px;
    font-family: neuebold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 0.9;
  }

  .contacts {
    border-right: none;
    padding: 0;
  }

  a {
    padding-right: 65px;
  }

  .vind {
    color: #FDDB27;
  }

  .logo {
    font-family: specify;
    font-size: 28px;
    border-top: none;
  }

  .sun {
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>teleginsmm</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<div class="holst">
  <div class="border">
    <header class="header">
      <nav class="navbar">
        <ul class="ul">
          <li class="textheader"><a class="logo">telegin<span class="vind">smm</span></a></li>
          <li class="textheader"><a>кто</a></li>
          <li class="textheader"><a>зачем</a></li>
          <li class="textheader"><a>услуги</a></li>
          <li class="textheader"><a class="contacts">контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <img class ="sun" src="assets/img/150.svg" alt="Ой, какая-то проблемкпа">
    <div class="promotions">
      <p class="smm">smm</p>
      <p class="promotion">про</p>
      <p class="promotion">дви</p>
      <p class="promotion">жение</p>
    </div>
    <div class="secondpage">
      <p>sdsfdsgfdfsfsdgdrgsfd</p>
      <p>sdsfdsgfdfsfsdgdrgsfd</p>
      <p>sdsfdsgfdfsfsdgdrgsfd</p>
      <p>sdsfdsgfdfsfsdgdrgsfd</p>
      <p>sdsfdsgfdfsfsdgdrgsfd</p>
      <p>sdsfdsgfdfsfsdgdrgsfd</p>
      <p>sdsfdsgfdfsfsdgdrgsfd</p>
      <p>sdsfdsgfdfsfsdgdrgsfd</p>
      <p>sdsfdsgfdfsfsdgdrgsfd</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как поместить svg овалы под текст продвижение?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте задать z-index классу sun

Comment: Не реагирует на это

Comment: реагирует, только это не  лечит.  поставьте `z-index:1; position:relative` классу `.promotions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш круг не работает, пришлось подключить свой.
Нужно было родительскому элементу прописать **position: relative;**
ну и поиграться чуток с маржинами и размером круга:

```css
  body, h1, h2,h3,h4, p,a {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font-weight: normal;
      }

    @font-face {
      src: url(../fonts/NeueMachina-Regular.woff);
      font-family: "neuenormal";
      font-weight:normal;
    }
      
    @font-face {
      src: url(../fonts/NeueMachina-Ultrabold.woff);
      font-family: "neuebold";
      font-weight: bold;
    }

      

    @font-face {
      src: url(../fonts/SpecifyPERSONAL-ExExpBlack.woff);
      font-family: "specify";
      font-weight: bold;
    }



      .holst {
          /*background: url(../img/back.jpg) center no-repeat;*/
          background-size: cover;
          background-color: darkslategrey;
          
      }

      .border {
        border: solid;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-color: white;
        border-top: none;
        border-bottom: none;
        width: 1400px;
        margin:0 auto;
      }

      .header {
        font-family: AvenirNext;
        list-style: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }
      
      .ul {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        border: solid;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-color: white;
        border-left: none;
        border-right: none;
        border-top: none;
      }
      
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color:white;
      }

      .textheader {
        color:white;
        font-size: 30px;
        list-style: none;
        font-family: neuebold;
      }

      a {
        border: solid;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-left: none;
        border-bottom: none;
      }

      .navbar {
      }
      
      .promotions {
        padding-top: 100px;
        padding-left: 50px;
     position: relative;
      }



      .sun {
        width: 250px;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left:-57px;
        margin-top: -50px;      
      }


      .sun2{
        width: 300px;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left:-57px;
        margin-top: 100px;      
      }

       .sun3{
        width: 300px;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left:-57px;
        margin-top: 290px;      
       }

       .sun4{
        width: 470px;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left:-57px;
        margin-top: 400px;      
        }


      .smm {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: specify;
        font-size:55px;
        -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #00B1D2;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        line-height: 0.9;
      }

      .promotion {
        color: #00B1D2;
        font-size:100px;
        font-family: neuebold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        line-height: 0.9;
        position:relative;
      }

      .contacts {
        border-right: none;
        padding: 0;
      }

      a {
        padding-right: 65px;
      }

      .vind {
        color: #FDDB27;
      }

      .logo {
        font-family: specify;
        font-size: 28px;
        border-top: none;
      }
```

```html
 <div class="holst">

      <div class="border">
        <header class="header">
          <nav class="navbar">
            <ul class="ul">
              <li class="textheader"><a class="logo">telegin<span class="vind">smm</span></a></li>
              <li class="textheader"><a>кто</a></li>
              <li class="textheader"><a>зачем</a></li>
              <li class="textheader"><a>услуги</a></li>
              <li class="textheader"><a class="contacts">контакты</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </header>
         

        <div class="promotions">
        <img class ="sun" src="https://i.ibb.co/0B762gS/pngwing-com.png" alt="Ой, какая-то проблемкпа">
         <img class ="sun2" src="https://i.ibb.co/0B762gS/pngwing-com.png" alt="Ой, какая-то проблемкпа">

         <p class="smm">smm</p>
          <p class="promotion">про</p>
          <p class="promotion">дви</p>
          <p class="promotion">жение</p>
        </div>
        <div class="secondpage">
        
          <p>sdsfdsgfdfsfsdgdrgsfd</p>
          <p>sdsfdsgfdfsfsdgdrgsfd</p>
          <p>sdsfdsgfdfsfsdgdrgsfd</p>
          <p>sdsfdsgfdfsfsdgdrgsfd</p>
          <p>sdsfdsgfdfsfsdgdrgsfd</p>
          <p>sdsfdsgfdfsfsdgdrgsfd</p>
          <p>sdsfdsgfdfsfsdgdrgsfd</p>
          <p>sdsfdsgfdfsfsdgdrgsfd</p>
          <p>sdsfdsgfdfsfsdgdrgsfd</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```